# How to check for type errors in errors.Errorf()?

Tags: go

Calls to string formatting functions like fmt.Printf seem to be a weak spot for the Go compiler. I end up with lots of bugs (using the wrong formatter after a refactor, forgetting to include all the arguments) that only reveal themselves at runtime. So I end up having to squint hard every time I write one of these.

I did some research today and discovered `go tool vet`, which appears to work for fmt.Printf, but it doesn't catch mistakes in errors.Errorf (see below).

```
import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func ReturnError(s string, i int) error {
    // Swap %d and %s, and forget to include the second argument
    return errors.Errorf("invalid arguments %d and %s", s)
}
```

Is there an analog to `go tool vet` that can capture string formatting errors in errors.Errorf()? Also, for my own understanding, why is this such a hard problem? It doesn't seem any more difficult for the Go compiler to catch string formatting type errors than any other kind of type errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `go vet` which functions to check for (compare [godoc.org/cmd/vet](https://godoc.org/cmd/vet#hdr-Printf_family)):

```
$ cat x.go
package main

import "github.com/pkg/errors"

func ReturnError(s string, i int) error {
    // Swap %d and %s, and forget to include the second argument
    return errors.Errorf("invalid arguments %d and %s", s)
}
$ go vet x.go 
$ go vet -printfuncs Errorf x.go 
# command-line-arguments
./x.go:7: Errorf format %d has arg s of wrong type string
```

It's not straightforward to do this better for a number of reasons:

- Format strings are run-time values: You might well call `fmt.Sprintf(prefix + "%s", ...)`. So it is impossible to catch all invalid format strings at compile time.
- Format strings don't have a special type. Hence the compiler can't easily determine that some function (`errors.Errorf` in this case) expects its arguments to behave like `fmt.Printf` just by looking at the function definition.

Comment: Ah, -printfuncs is just what I was looking for. One clarification: what do you mean by "format strings are run-time values"? It seems that they can be analyzed at compile-time like anything else (since the types of the arguments are known).

Comment: I tried to clarify the part about why this is difficult, does it make sense now?

Comment: Ah okay, you’re saying that the first art of Printf can be a variable whose value isn’t known at compile time. It does seem like in most uses the first arg is a constant string, but I guess Go doesn’t want to disambiguate these cases?